# Displaying items from database into a listView with different data with different items

Tags: php, android, mysql, listview

I am currently making a simple Android discussion forum. I can successfully save and retrieve data from the database (`phpMyAdmin` from 000webhost). I can also display the data retrieve into the `listView`.

As it is a forum, different items (topics) should have different replies. So I have 2 different tables, one is `ForumData` (to store the topics) and another one is `ReplyData` (to store replies). Both tables have a topic_id, which is used to refer to different topics, e.g. replies of `topic_id = 3 in ReplyData` are related to `topic_id = 3 in ForumData.`

Normally, replies of `topic_id = 3` should only be displayed when clicked into topic 3. But every time I click into different topics, all the replies are displayed, no matter what the topic_id is. So, how can I display related replies in a related topic only? Should I do it in the php file or the application?

This is my php file in retrieving the reply data:

```
<?php

//personal data hidden
$con = mysql_connect();
mysql_select_db('db', $con);

$r = mysql_query('SELECT ReplyData.reply_user, ReplyData.reply_content,   ReplyData.reply_datetime FROM
ReplyData INNER JOIN ForumData ON ForumData.topic_id = ReplyData.topic_id');
$out = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)){
  $out[] = $row;
}

print(json_encode($out));
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

This is my adapter for the listView:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ReplyItemList> {
    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(ContentPage.this, R.layout.layout_reply, itemList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // make sure we have a view to work with
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_reply, parent, false);
        }

        // find the activity to work with
        ReplyItemList currentActivity = itemList.get(position);
        //get current time and date

        // fill the view
        TextView makeReplyUser = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvRespondent);
        makeReplyUser.setText("Re: " + currentActivity.getRespondent() + " ");
        TextView makeReplyContent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvReplyContent);
        makeReplyContent.setText(currentActivity.getReplyContent());
        TextView makeReplyDatetime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvReplyDatetime);
        makeReplyDatetime.setText("(" + currentActivity.getDateTime() + ")");

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

This is the listView populating method:

```
private void populateListView() {
        adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.replyList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

[Log.i(fetchedTopicID + " " + respondent + " " + content + " " + datetime + " ", "json result");](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSXHm.png)

Comment: You should also provide your app code, on how you retrieve it and how you store it. :)

Comment: @sept   it is not the data retrieve and store problems as they work just fine. I am wondering if it is the populating problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. Also provide tablename.field_name if the field names are different in both tables. For eg; ReplyData.reply_user or ForumData.reply_content.

```
SELECT reply_user, reply_content, reply_datetime FROM
ReplyData INNER JOIN ForumData ON ForumData.topic_id = ReplyData.topic_id
```

Comment: I have tried this query, it makes no difference with my original one. All the details in the ReplyData are still displayed in every listView item. The field_name in both tables are different, but I just want to retrieve those in one table, the other table is used to indicate the location of those retrieved record.

Comment: If the field names are different, could you please try by adding tablename.field_name in the query?

Comment: Sorry that I am very new to database. I have no idea how to add it. I have tables ForumData (topic_id, topic, username, original_content, original_datetime) and ReplyData (topic_id, reply_user, reply_content, reply_datetime)

Comment: SELECT ReplyData.reply_user, ReplyData.reply_content, ReplyData.reply_datetime FROM
ReplyData INNER JOIN ForumData ON ForumData.topic_id = ReplyData.topic_id

Comment: thanks for your help, but it still makes no difference :-(

Comment: I am wondering if that should be the populating problem. I have added my display method. I wish u could take a look if u have time.

Comment: Could you please post your json result when topic_id=3 ?

Comment: Updated. the ids are correctly retrieved. So I still think that it should be the display problem. But I just don't know how to do that